# inserting data from mongodb through node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, insert

I have to insert data to mongodb through node js.
(+edit)
Here is my inserting code

```
app.post('/composemail', express.urlencoded({extended:true}), function(req,res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('emailList');
    var sender = "abc@mail.com";
    var recipient = req.body.recipient;
    var title = req.body.title;
    var time = req.body.time;
    var content = req.body.content;
    var mailbox = req.body.mailbox;
    var newmail = {'sender':sender,'recipient':recipient,'title':title,'time':time,'content':content,'mailbox':mailbox};
    collection.insert(newmail, function(err,result) {
        if (err === null) {
            res.send("Successfully added!");
        } else res.send(err);
    })
})
```

(+edit)
This is my html code. The form is generated by script.
function compose is triggered when a "compose" button is clicked

```
function compose() {
  emailDIV.innerHTML = "<form name='compose' action='/composemail' method='post'> New Message";
  emailDIV.innerHTML += "<p>To: <input type='textbox' name='recipient'></p>";
  emailDIV.innerHTML += "<p>Subject: <input type='textbox' name='title'></p>";
  emailDIV.innerHTML += "<p><input type='textarea' name='content' class='textarea'></p>";
  emailDIV.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='mailbox' value='"+nowBox+"'>";
  date = new Date();
  time = date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0]+" "+date.toDateString();
  emailDIV.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='time' value='"+time+"'>";
  emailDIV.innerHTML += "<input type='submit' value='Send'> </form>";
}
```

However if the form is directly written in HTML, it works!

```
<div id="test">
  <form name='compose' action='/composemail' method='post'>
    New Message
    <p>To: <input type='textbox' name='recipient'></p>
    <p>Subject: <input type='textbox' name='title'></p>
    <p><input type='textarea' name='content' class='textarea'></p>
    <input type='hidden' name='mailbox' value='Important'>
    <!--date = new Date();
    time = date.toTimeString().split(' ')[0]+" "+date.toDateString(); -->

    <input type='hidden' name='time' value='20:00:01 Wed Nov 06 2019'>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'> </form>
</div>
```

but the form has to be generated only when a button is clicked. What should I do?

Comment: What is the error message you getting, if any? Edit: Also, `insert` is deprecated, use `insertOne`.

Comment: I could not get any error message, even I write something like console.log("a string") nothing appears... and It seems that I have tried insertOne, also not working.... is no response after clicking

Comment: oh if thats the case I think the whole code is not running? let me add the html code at the question!

Comment: `const collection = db.collection('emailList')` perhaps you need this instead of db.get() to get collection of dbs.

Comment: I think that's not a problem because updating and getting works perfectly fine! And I just figured out which part is the problem. If the form is not generated by script, the inserting works! But the form has to shown after clicking a button. what should I do...

Comment: `action='/composemail'` you are using in your html form , so here where is matching app.post('/composemail') in nodejs?

Comment: forgot to update it here, inside my app.js it is app.post('/composemail') just edited, sorry! ><

Comment: I think the problem now is not on the js side but html side

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom you need this form html parser in order to work with nodejs properly.

Comment: After adding the following 2 lines: const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom; when the body is loaded, the database is not being retrieved even before I press the compose button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solved by moving a hidden div. Thank you all of you for helping.